# Postfix TLS configuration

Tags: postfix, tls

I am in the middle of setting up a postfix server on Arch Linux. It seems to be working ok so far - I can successfully speak to it via `telnet localhost 25`. However, when I try to connect using openssl's `s_client`, it complains:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:25
CONNECTED(00000003)
140243743024808:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:766:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 228 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

and exits with status 1.

Relevant part of `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_tls_key_file = /path/to/server.key.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /path/to/server.crt.pem
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /path/to/ca.pem

smtpd_tls_security_level = may
```

I also have the key and cert in non-pem formats, and they are working fine with another service that uses them (an xmpp server).

I have found [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix#Using_Port_587_for_Secure_Submission) saying that to achieve this, I need to uncomment a line in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and use port 587 instead of 25. This gives me the same outfrom from `openssl s_client` as above.

How do I convince postfix to use TLS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use port 587 for tls, because it is application protocol independent.

I get exactly the same result as you from `openssl s_client -connect localhost:25`, but tls is working properly on my server.

Currently i have no access to my personal wiki, so i couldn't paste the correct command to check your tls configuration on your system. But you could use [CheckTLS](http://www.checktls.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to read about [STARTTLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STARTTLS). It comes down to this: start an unencrypted plain text connection and upgrade to TLS later. The `openssl` command does not use this and wants to do an SSL/TLS handshake directly.

The 'general' de facto configuration for MTAs is to configure it to have STARTTLS available on port 587, plain SSL/TLS on 465 and insecure with STARTTLS option on port 25. This is no standard as far as I know, just the way major service providers seem to do it.